# Average/Median of strings in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of strings in different cells:

- A1: Cat
- B1: Dog
- C1: Cat
- D1: Lion
- E1: Cat

---

I want to return the string that appear the most (in this example it'll be "Cat"). I understand that average or median are for numbers only, but I'm trying to find the equivalent for strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=INDEX(A1:A,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A)),COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SINGLE(SORT(FLATTEN(A1:E1), FLATTEN(COUNTIF(A1:E1, A1:E1)), ))
```

[image]